# Excluding results and performing an insert with SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Table a

```
Rowid              Msgid        Userid
1                   3             55
2                   3             56
3                   3             57
4                   4             55
5                   4             56
```

Table Group

```
RowID              GroupID            UseriD
1                      2               55
2                      2               56
3                      2               57
4                      2               58
5                      2               59
6                      2               60
7                      3               60
8                      3               55
```

Here there is a table `a` and `group` table. Rowid primary keys

I want to insert rows into table a

This query will

Insert rows into table a i.e for msgid 3 there is already 55 56 57 so it has to insert only 58 59 60.

```
Insert into 
table a (msgid,Userid) 
values(@msgid,@userid) 
where userid not in table a 
where tbl_a.msgid=3 
and tbl_group.groupid = 2
```

For Msgid 3 I want to check if there are any group members (groupID 2) associated in table a, if not then add a row to it.
 ie add to table a

```
rowid    Msgid    Userid
  6        3        58
  7        3        59
  8        3        60
```

So I wont insert the userid 55,56,57 because it is already in the table a for msgid 3. How to do a query for this scenario

Comment: You should have unique combined indexes with Msgid and Userid to be able to use `INSERT IGNORE` or `ON DUPLICATE KEY`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
 Insert IGNORE into 
 table a (msgid,Userid) 
 values(@msgid,@userid) 
 where userid not in table a 
 where tbl_a.msgid=3 
 and tbl_group.groupid = 2
```

I am considering that your insert query is correct...

Good Luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite simple:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_GROUP
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
WHERE ... -- you can have or not have a where clause as you like
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE;
```